# Toolbar overlapping with elements in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am implementing a list view in my app. I am trying to build my app for android 6.0 and chosen the theme "DarkActionBar". I am having this code right now in activity_main.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.www.mynotes.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have just added a listview (replacing a textview) in this code. Rest of code was already there when I created my project.

Right now I am adding some items randomly in the listview. **Now the problem is, the top most item of list view gets behind the toolbar as shown in the image below**. How to fix it? I want this listview to start below the toolbar.

[image]

Comment: What does this question have to do with Android Studio? Android Studio is an IDE for Android development. Your issue is IDE independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `app:layout_behavior` to your `LiveView` :

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But can you please tell me, where is this appbar_scrolling_view_behavior come from. There is no resource like this in strings.xml.